# Why is my For Loop multiplying every String

Tags: python, python-3.x

Im trying a python exercise where you are supposed to clean and list a huge string. Im facing a problem which is that my last for loop is making every string appears multiple times.

I have already tried to copy exactly what they do on the walkthough video (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=x1AxPYJwHCw&feature=youtu.be&t=300)

```
daily_sales = \`enter code here`
"""Edith Mcbride   ;,;$1.21   ;,;   white ;,; 
09/15/17   ,Herbert Tran   ;,;   $7.29;,; 
white&blue;,;   09/15/17 ,Paul Clarke ;,;$12.52 
;,;   white&blue ;,; 09/15/17 ,Lucille Caldwell   
;,;   $5.13   ;,; white   ;,; 09/15/17,
Eduardo George   ;,;$20.39;,; white&yellow 
;,;09/15/17   ,   Danny Mclaughlin;,;$30.82;,;   
purple ;,;09/15/17 ,Stacy Vargas;,; $1.85   ;,; 
purple&yellow ;,;09/15/17,   Shaun Brock;,; 
$17.98;,;purple&yellow ;,; 09/15/17 , 
Erick Harper ;,;$17.41;,; blue ;,; 09/15/17, 
Michelle Howell ;,;$28.59;,; blue;,;   09/15/17   , 
Carroll Boyd;,; $14.51;,;   purple&blue   ;,;   
09/15/17   , Teresa Carter   ;,; $19.64 ;,; 
white;,;09/15/17   ,   Ja`enter code here`cob Kennedy ;,; $11.40   
;,; white&red   ;,; 09/15/17, Craig Chambers;,; 
$8.79 ;,; white&blue&red   ;,;09/15/17   , Peggy Bell;,; $8.65 ;,;blue   ;,; 09/15/17,   Kenneth Cunningham ;,;   $10.53;,;   green&blue   ;,; 
09/15/17   ,   Marvin Morgan;,;   $16.49;,; 
green&blue&red   ;,;   09/15/17 ,Marjorie Russell 
;,; $6.55 ;,;   green&blue&red;,;   09/15/17 ,
Israel Cummings;,;   $11.86   ;,;black;,;  
09/15/17,   June Doyle   ;,;   $22.29 ;,;  
black&yellow ;,;09/15/17 , Jaime Buchanan   ;,;   
$8.35;,;   white&black&yellow   ;,;   09/15/17,   
Rhonda Farmer;,;$2.91 ;,;   white&black&yellow   
;,;09/15/17, Darren Mckenzie ;,;$22.94;,;green 
;,;09/15/17,Rufus Malone;,;$4.70   ;,; green&yellow 
;,; 09/15/17   ,Hubert Miles;,;   $3.59   
;,;green&yellow&blue;,;   09/15/17   , Joseph Bridges  ;,;$5.66   ;,; green&yellow&purple&blue 
;,;   09/15/17 , Sergio Murphy   ;,;$17.51   ;,;   
black   ;,;   09/15/17 , Audrey Ferguson ;,; 
$5.54;,;black&blue   ;,;09/15/17 ,Edna Williams ;,; 
$17.13;,; black&blue;,;   09/15/17,   Randy Fleming;,;   $21.13 ;,;black ;,;09/15/17 ,Elisa Hart;,; $0.35   ;,; black&purple;,;   09/15/17   ,
Ernesto Hunt ;,; $13.91   ;,;   black&purple ;,;   
09/15/17,   Shannon Chavez   ;,;$19.26   ;,; 
yellow;,; 09/15/17   , Sammy Cain;,; $5.45;,;   
yellow&red ;,;09/15/17 ,   Steven Reeves ;,;$5.50   
;,;   yellow;,;   09/15/17, Ruben Jones   ;,; 
$14.56 ;,;   yellow&blue;,;09/15/17 , Essie Hansen;,;   $7.33   ;,;   yellow&blue&red
;,; 09/15/17   ,   Rene Hardy   ;,; $20.22   ;,; 
black ;,;   09/15/17 ,   Lucy Snyder   ;,; $8.67   
;,;black&red  ;,; 09/15/17 ,Dallas Obrien ;,;   
$8.31;,;   black&red ;,;   09/15/17,   Stacey Payne 
;,;   $15.70   ;,;   white&black&red ;,;09/15/17   
,   Tanya Cox   ;,;   $6.74   ;,;yellow   ;,; 
09/15/17 , Melody Moran ;,;   $30.84   
;,;yellow&black;,;   09/15/17 , Louise Becker   ;,; 
$12.31 ;,; green&yellow&black;,;   09/15/17 ,
Ryan Webster;,;$2.94 ;,; yellow ;,; 09/15/17 
,Justin Blake ;,; $22.46   ;,;white&yellow ;,;   
09/15/17,   Beverly Baldwin ;,;   $6.60;,;   
white&yellow&black ;,;09/15/17   ,   Dale Brady   
;,;   $6.27 ;,; yellow   ;,;09/15/17 ,Guadalupe Potter ;,;$21.12   ;,; yellow;,; 09/15/17   , 
Desiree Butler ;,;$2.10   ;,;white;,; 09/15/17  
,Sonja Barnett ;,; $14.22 ;,;white&black;,;   
09/15/17, Angelica Garza;,;$11.60;,;white&black   
;,;   09/15/17   ,   Jamie Welch   ;,; $25.27   ;,; 
white&black&red ;,;09/15/17   ,   Rex Hudson   
;,;$8.26;,;   purple;,; 09/15/17"""
#------------------------------------------------
# Start coding below!
daily_sales_replaced = daily_sales.replace(';,;','+')
daily_transactions = daily_sales_replaced.split(',')
daily_transactions_split = []
for transaction in daily_transactions:
  daily_transactions_split.append(transaction.split('+'))

print(daily_transactions_split)

transactions_clean = []
for transaction in daily_transactions_split:
  transaction_clean = []
  for data_point in transaction:
    transaction_clean.append(data_point.strip(" "))
    transactions_clean.append(transaction_clean)

print(transactions_clean)
```

if you run the print function at the end you will se that the result is something like this:

```
[['Edith Mcbride', '$1.21', 'white', '\n09/15/17'], ['Edith Mcbride', '$1.21', 'white', '\n09/15/17'], ['Edith Mcbride', '$1.21', 'white', '\n09/15/17'], ['Edith Mcbride', '$1.21', 'white', '\n09/15/17'], ['Herbert Tran', '$7.29', '\nwhite&blue', '09/15/17'], ['Herbert Tran', '$7.29', '\nwhite&blue', '09/15/17'], ['Herbert Tran', '$7.29', '\nwhite&blue', '09/15/17'], ['Herbert Tran', '$7.29', '\nwhite&blue', '09/15/17'],...
```

The expected would be that every name, price, etc appeared only once

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account. [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) applies here.  Please reduce this to a small string and only the failing code.

Comment: you can check out [this github code](https://github.com/greyhairandglasses/VSCode/blob/3013db53869990007ed09010ecb3c18a1b473c0a/thread.py)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like a simple indentation error:

```
transactions_clean = []
for transaction in daily_transactions_split:
  transaction_clean = []
  for data_point in transaction:
    transaction_clean.append(data_point.strip(" "))
  transactions_clean.append(transaction_clean)
```

Originally, it would have appended the transaction_clean list for every data_point in transaction.